# How can I get new chrome extension id before submit it for review?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have developed one extension which takes session of my site by opening site in new tab and my site is talk with my chrome extension.

For send message from my website to chrome extension. I used my extension's id into my website.
I generate that extension id for development purpose only. Now I want to publish my extension and want to submit for review.

But problem is that , without my website., extension won't work as expected. So I need new extension id that will be generate after publish on Chrome Web Store and then I have to update my website to update id of extension into my website.

So how can I get uploaded extension's id before submit for review. So that I can update my website first before extension going for review.

Does any one have same kind of scenario ?

I don't know how google review our extension. So it needs to be working perfect before submit it in review.

Answer (score 1):

You could upload the Extension to the Chrome Store but without publishing.

Then you could  download it from the Chrome Dashboard.
Extract crx file. It is an ZIP File or use an Crx Viewer. (https://robwu.nl/crxviewer/)

the manifest.json should now contain a "Key" entry.
(https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/manifest/key/)

Ensure that the Key is the same value for your local build. This should result into the same id.

When you Upload the Extension to the Chrome Store again, ensure that the Key entry is removed. Otherwise the Chrome Dashboard will reject the Upload.